# Communication between views

Tags: mvvm-light

I am abit confused about how to setup the messaging between views.  What I am doing is using a radtabcontrol in my mainpage.  Each view that is launched after that is bound to a new tab.  When the tab needs to be terminated, i.e. user requests a close or it is no longer required, I need to communicate back to the mainpage so it can terminate the view and close the tab.

Can someone help me find a tutorial or perhaps provide sample code using Messenger and RelayCommand to do this?

Comment: You should probably tag this question with "Silverlight" or "WPF" depending on your scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the constructor of your MainPage (or whatever):

```
Messenger.Default.Register<string>(this, MessageReceived);
```

The MessageReceived method (also in MainPage):

```
private void MessageReceived(string message)
{
    if (message == "SomeTabWasClosed")
    {
        //Do the necessary clean-up
    }
}
```

Then when you need to send the message (maybe in your tab Views or their ViewModels):

```
Messenger.Default.Send("SomeTabWasClosed");
```